# Post a Tweet contain hashtag with API

Tags: php, api, twitter, twitter-oauth

Hey guys I'm trying to post tweet with twitter API.

```
$parameters = [
            'status'    => 'Here is a #hashtag ',
        ];
$result = $connection->post('statuses/update', $parameters);
```

And it will successfully post to twitter.
but i'm the only one who can see it and others can't.
it's hidden for them.

Comment: Can you give us an example Tweet so we can see what the problem is? Also, which Twitter library are you using?

Comment: EX: This is a #Hashtag

Comment: twitter 1.1 api and and twitteroauth

Comment: And this is the library that i use:https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth

Comment: Can you show us the actual Tweet that you sent? As in, the URL on Twitter.

Comment: It's in persian.https://twitter.com/amirpirmoradian/status/934159717450084352

Comment: That tweet doesn't exist. Can you see anything at that URL?